# VB.net Could not find directory

Tags: vb.net, directory, find

This is the full code.
http://pastebin.com/cx9Tk0n3

I'm having a problem that, after downloading the mod, all works perfectly, the RAR file is located into the document folder while the extraxted content (@Mod) is under LauncherArma under Documents folder.

While clicking on the button to install the mod, starting from line 184, I've this error:

[image]

```
Private Sub FlatButton6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton6.Click
   If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\LauncherArma") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\LauncherArma", FileIO.DeleteDirectoryOption.DeleteAllContents)
    End If


    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\LauncherArma\modsname.txt") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\LauncherArma\modsname.txt")
    End If

    My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\LauncherArma")
    UnRar(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\Addon.rar", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\LauncherArma")
    Dim ligne As String
    My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile("FTP ADDRESS. Hidden for security. Don't worry, the download files works!/modsname.txt", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\LauncherArma\modsname.txt")
    Dim sr As New StreamReader(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) & "\LauncherArma\modsname.txt")
    While sr.Peek <> -1
        ligne = sr.ReadLine()
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) & "\LauncherArma\" & ligne, directory & "\" & ligne, True)
    End While
    PictureBox1.Visible = True
    FlatButton6.Visible = False
    FlatProgressBar1.Visible = False
    FlatLabel1.Visible = False
    FlatLabel2.Visible = False
    FlatLabel3.Visible = False
End Sub
```

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Waiting your reply!

Regards

Comment: Could you add just the relevant code here? None will read that wall of code. The code in the button click that triggers the error should be enough

Comment: @Steve It's from line 170 to 184

Comment: Between the reasons for exception for the CopyDirectory method the only one that raises this exception is the one that says: _The source directory does not exist_ So or you don't have permissions or the directory source doesn't exist. I would check line by line the contents of the file downloaded by FTP against the structure of the source directory

Comment: All the files exists. The permission, using BulletProof for the FTP  are set as permission for the files only read and the directories as list. 
In fast, while the files are downloaded, as I said below, The RAR is located to the main document folder while the zipped file is into ArmaLauncher under Document folder...

Comment: =Problem Solved! Had to delete the folder from APPData!

Comment: I can only suggest to start your debugger and proceed line by line in that function checking if the variables are exactly as you expect them to be.